# How many jobs should i start when using make?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, compilation

I wonder what number of jobs would be the most effective one when i run 'make -j x'. Is it the number of cores or would it be better to use even more jobs?

Comment: Just try it. You don't have that many choices. You can use "time make ..." to find out the wall clock time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good value is `number of CPUs + 1`.

So if you have a recent quadcore CPU which has hyperthreading, use 9. If you have a dualcore without hyperthreading, use 3.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen recommendations for `-j(2N+1)` where `N` is the number of cores. I have no idea where the number came from, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 3rd Generation Intel Core i7 (quad-core) on my laptop.
I realized that `make -j5` does not take advantage of all the parallelism the i7 can offer.

`make -j9`, however, does not go 100% cpu usage either while compiling most packages. Compiling the GNU kernel is way faster here (and uses 100% cpu) if I do something bigger than 10, like `make -j18` or something.

I guess it's trial and error.

Comment: My Computer Architechture II professor would kill me if he saw the "I guess it's trial and error" part.